# Energy Momentum Tensor for massive Real Scalar Field in GR with metric signature (+ - - -)

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, conventions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I wanted to calculate the Energy Momentum Tensor for the massive real scalar field in Kerr Background. But instead of the usual (- + + +) metric signature, I have to use the (+ - - -) signature for the metric. Does the form of Energy Momentum tensor change, if the metric signature is changed?

Comment: Hi and welcome to PSE! Could you please post a link/reference to the same solved problem in the -+++ metric?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228185/2451